# how to filter out only float data type from a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column that looks like this:

```
col1
20.5
21.2
21.2
17315/06/2021 09:06:481032.14310134.91082996.3001047998.93380132341231
0060232346956263174
$365140110030
$36516011007C27
$3651501100E743
```

I want that only the floating point values will remain in the column
I've tried various replace methods, no luck:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].replace(r'/ [ ^\d.] / g', '', regex=True, inplace=False)
```

appears that it doesn't do anything

or

```
df['Temp'] = df['Temp'].replace(r'/ [ ^\d.] / g', '', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

places all values as `NaN`

Comment: What is your expected output (for each row of the provided column)?

Comment: As an aside if you're going to use `inplace=True` you shouldn't assign back.

Comment: the out come should leave only floaters in the column, like:

Comment: if your input is string dtype, what is your criterion for "*only the floating point values*"? I mean, is "1" a float? Or does it have to be "1.0"?

Comment: '''20.5
21.2
21.2

Comment: only 1.0 is a "good" value

Comment: And if there's a float nested within `"This is a cell with a float 5.4"` should it produce `5.4` or `NaN`?

Comment: it should produce only 5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an option could be to find all "digit-dot-digit" sequences in all the column's elements, and cast to numeric if there is exactly one match:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [
            20.5,
            21.2,
            21.2,
            "17315/06/2021 09:06:481032.14310134.91082996.3001047998.93380132341231",
            "0060232346956263174",
            "$365140110030",
            "$36516011007C27",
            "$3651501100E743",
            "This is a cell with a float 5.4",
            -50.0 ]})

# with an apply/lambda
# df['floats'] = df['col1'].astype(str).str.findall("\-?\d+\.\d+").apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(*x) if len(x)==1 else None)

# you can also avoid the apply/lambda with a temporary series:
s = df['col1'].astype(str).str.findall("\-?\d+\.\d+")
df['floats'] = pd.to_numeric(s[s.str.len() == 1].str[0])

print(df['floats'])
0    20.5
1    21.2
2    21.2
3     NaN
4     NaN
5     NaN
6     NaN
7     NaN
8     5.4
9   -50.0
Name: floats, dtype: float64
```

Comment: returns: TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

Comment: @Aby_g ok seems you have a mixed datatype column as input. Made an edit that accounts for that. That's why it is so important to provide a [mre] with the questions :)

Comment: hi, my data got a bit complex, and now all of the outputs is 0.0. something like this : `Temperature 1:31.8, Temperature 2:-50.0,`

Comment: @Aby_g you might need to adjust the regex; I've modified the example to include negative values.

Comment: i've noticed that only 1 value is produced from this regex expression on my data and it is: 4.18 from the line : `198;HV,INTERNAL;SV,4.18;PV,7001` i assume that there is sign that is messing up the expression

Comment: i have found the problem (i think), when i've played around with my txt file i've noticed that the problem with the code is dealing with more then one floating value. i think that a good strategy will be clearing out all the other "Temperature : ? " fields accept the first one (he's the only one that is relevant), the problem is that pd replace isn't working for me, perhaps i'm doing something wrong?

Comment: @Aby_g if you have another, specific question that isn't covered here, better open a new question instead of trying to solve it via the comments section here ;-)